# AWS Linux CloudWatch - Metric for Top 5 processes and memory consumed

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-web-services, sh, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to publish a custom metric (cloudwatch) to get the top 5 processes and their memory consumption in Linux machines.

Currently for Windows I am using the following powershell script:

```
$Processes = get-process | Sort-Object CPU -desc | Group-Object -Property 

ProcessName | Select-Object -first 5
#$Processes = get-process | Group-Object -Property ProcessName

foreach($Process in $Processes)
{
    $mem = ($Process.Group|Measure-Object WorkingSet -Sum).Sum
    $memMB = $mem/1MB
    $Obj = New-Object psobject
    $Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $Process.Name
    $Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Mem -Value $memMB
    $Obj

    #Write-Host $Process.Name
    aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --metric-name $Process.Name --namespace TopProcesses --value $memMB
}
```

At the moment this is working fine for Windows, but I am having a lot of trouble porting a similar concept on Linux machines, if anyone can give me some help on this issue, it would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: If this information could be retrieved through lambda I would be able to find a solution, however, I am unsure as to how I should go about grabbing the linux instance information through python.

Answer (score -1):

I really think that would be better use for that some metrics aggregator. For example [Telegraf](https://docs.influxdata.com/telegraf/v1.7/) or [Collectd](https://collectd.org/features.shtml). Both solutions support Windows and Linux distros.

Telegraf has nice yaml config. You just put cloudwatch in output and that's it. Ready solutions help you avoid of development/support custom code.

As for shell script you could obtain top 5 processes by memory like that:

`PIDS=$(ps aux --sort -rss | tail -n +2 | head -n 5 | awk '{print $2}')`

Above script grabs pids of processes. There are a lot of methods how grab memory utilization by PID. For example you could do:

`cat /proc/$pid/status`

Comment: Is there a way to do this through python by any chance?

Comment: You could for sure do it by Python as well. Use **psutil** for that. It is cross-platform solution.
`pids = psutil.pids()`  It returns all processes. Grab process by PID by `process = psutil.Process(<some_pid>)`. And get memory info by `rocess.get_memory_info()`.

Use it in your script. It is exactly what are you looking for.